# UIView.transitionWithView inside a UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create some animations with a delay between them so I decided to use `UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`.

The problem is that it happens all at the same time. Here is my code:

**animateKeyframesWithDuration**:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: nil, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
        self.flipTransition(container: self.container500, view1: self.button500, view2: self.buttonDivision)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/5, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
        self.flipTransition(container: self.container100, view1: self.button100, view2: self.buttonMultiplication)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2/5, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
        self.flipTransition(container: self.container50, view1: self.button50, view2: self.buttonSubtraction)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(3/5, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
        self.flipTransition(container: self.container10, view1: self.button10, view2: self.buttonAddition)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(4/5, relativeDuration: 1/5, animations: {
        self.flipTransitionForConvertAndEqual(container: self.containerConvert, convertView: self.buttonConvert, equalView: self.buttonEqual)
    })
    }, completion: { finished in    
})
```

**transitionWithView**:

```
private func flipTransitionForConvertAndEqual(#container: UIView, convertView: UIView, equalView: UIView) {
    var transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions!
    let duration = kAnimationDuration

    // case where equal is displayed
    if equalView.superview != nil {
        transitionOptions = .TransitionFlipFromLeft
    }
    else {
        transitionOptions = .TransitionFlipFromRight
    }

    UIView.transitionWithView(container, duration: duration, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        self.setConvertContainer(container: container, convertView: convertView, equalView: equalView)
        }, completion: nil)
}

private func flipTransition(#container: UIView, view1: UIView, view2: UIView) {
    var transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions!
    let duration = kAnimationDuration

    var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)

    if view1.superview != nil {
        views = (frontView: view1, backView: view2)
        transitionOptions = .TransitionFlipFromLeft
    }
    else {
        views = (frontView: view2, backView: view1)
        transitionOptions = .TransitionFlipFromRight
    }

    UIView.transitionWithView(container, duration: duration, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        self.addFrontViewToContainer(container, frontView: views.backView, backView: views.frontView)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

What did I do wrong? Can't figure it out.

Comment: Tried to do the same thing and saw the same behavior. I think the UIView transition cannot be embedded in the UIView animating keyframes, but rather runs independently.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> - (void)addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:(double)frameStartTime relativeDuration:(double)frameDuration animations:(void (^)(void))animations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
>
> // start time and duration are values between 0.0 and 1.0 specifying
>   time and duration relative to the overall time of the keyframe
>   animation

In your case you might want to do instaed of **1/5, 2/5, 3/5** for the **relativeStartTime** parameter **1 * (1/5), 2 * (1/5), 3 * (1/5)**,  and **1/5** for the duration, remember these are values relative to the total duration you specify for the **UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration..** method